# Optimization of Oracle Query

Tags: oracle11g

I have following query :

```
SELECT distinct A1 ,sum(total) as sum_total  FROM 
    (   
       SELECT  A1, A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,COUNT(A7) AS total,A8
       FROM (
            select a.*  from table1 a 
            left join (select * from table_reject where name = 'smith') b on A.A3 = B.B3 and A.A9 =B.B2
            where B.ID is null
            ) t1
       WHERE A8 >= NEXT_DAY ( trunc(to_date('17/09/2013 12:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) ,'SUN' )     
       GROUP BY 
       CUBE(A1, A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A8)
    )INN
    WHERE 
     INN.A1 IS NOT NULL AND
     INN.A2 IS NULL AND 
     INN.A3 IS NULL AND 
     INN.A4 IS NULL AND
     INN.A5 IS NULL AND 
     INN.A6 is NULL AND
     INN.A8 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY A1
    ORDER BY sum_total DESC ;
```

Total number records in table1 is around 8 million.
My problem is i need to optimize the above query in best possible way.I did tried to make index on column A8 of table1 and creating the index helped me to decrease the cost of query but execution time of query is more or less same when there was no index on the table1.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: can you post table structure and column data types, Column nullable types. did you consider how CUBE takes NULL value for any dimension columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CUBE operation on large data set is really expensive, so you need to check do you really need all that data in inner query. because i see you are doing COUNT in inner and then on the outer query you have SUM of counts. so in other words, give me the row count of A7 at for all combination A1-A8 (-A7). then get only SUM for selected combinations filtered by WHERE clause. we can sure optimize this by limiting CUBE on certain column itself but very obvious things so far i have notice are as follows.

if you use below query and have right index o Table1 and Table_reject then both query can utilize the Index and reduce the data set needs to be join and further processed.
I am not 100% sure but yes Partial CUBE processing is possible and need to check that.

clustered index --> Table1 need on A8 And Table_Reject need clustered index on NAME.

non-clustered index--> Table1 need on A3,A9and Table_reject need on B3,B2

```
    SELECT qry1.
    (
        SELECT  A1, A2,A3,A4,A5,A6,A7,A8
        FROM table1
        WHERE A8 >= NEXT_DAY ( trunc(to_date('17/09/2013 12:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) ,'SUN' )
    )qry1
    LEFT JOIN
    (
        select B3,B2,ID
        from table_reject 
        where name = 'smith'
    )qry2
        ON qry1.A3 = qry2.B3 and qry1.A9=qry2.B2
    WHERE qry2.ID IS NULL
```

**EDIT1:**

I tried to find out what will be the difference in CUBE operator result if you do it on all Columns or you do it on only columns that you need it in result set. what I found is the way CUBE function works you do not need to perform CUBE on all columns. because at the end you just care about combinations generated by CUBE where A1 and A8 is NOT NULL.
Try this link and see the output.

[enter link description here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/29437b/7)

Query 1 and Query2 is just inner most queries to compare the CUBE result set.

Query3 and Query4 is the same query that you are trying and you see the results are same in both case.

```
    DECLARE @NEXT_DAY DATE = NEXT_DAY ( trunc(to_date('17/09/2013 12:00:00','dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi:ss')) ,'SUN' )

    SELECT distinct A1 ,sum(total) as sum_total  FROM 
    (   
       SELECT  A1,COUNT(A7) AS total,A8
       FROM (
                select a.a1,a.a7,a.a8  
                from table1 a
                left join  (select * from table_reject where name = 'smith') b 
                on A.A3 = B.B3 and A.A9 =B.B2
                where B.ID is null
            ) t1
       WHERE A8 >= @NEXT_DAY
       GROUP BY 
       CUBE(A1,A8)
    )INN
    WHERE   INN.A1 IS NOT NULL AND
            INN.A8 IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY A1
    ORDER BY sum_total DESC ;
```

**EDIT3**

As I mentioned in the Comment this is a Round3 update. i can not change comment but i meant Edit3 instead Round3.

well the new change in your query is adding the `WHERE A8 >= @NEXT_DAY` condition in the inner most left join select `where A8 >= @NEXT_DAY AND B.ID is null` as well. that has improved the selection very much.

in your last comment you mentioned that query is taking 30-35 second and as you change the value of A8 it keep increasing. now with the execution time you didn't mentioned how much data is in the result set. **why that is important?**  because if my query is returning 5M rows as a final result set that will going to spend 90% time in just droping that data on to UI, or output file what ever output method you are using. but actual performance should be measured how soon the query has started giving first couple of rows. because by that time Optimizer has already decided the execution paln and DB is executing that plan. yet i agree that if query is returning 100 rows and taking 10 seconds then something can be wrong with execution plan.

to demo that what I did is I created the dummy data. and perfomred your query against it.
i have table Test_CubeData with 9M rows in it with the same column numbers and data type you explained for your Table1. I have second table Table_Reject with 80K rows with number of columns and its datatype I figured out from query. To test the extreme side of this table; name column has only one value "smith" and ID is null for all 80K rows. so column values that can affect inner left join result will be B2 and B3.

in these tests i do not have any index on both tables. both are heap. and you see the results are in still few seconds with acceptable range of data in result set. as my result data set increases the completion time increases. if i create explained indexes then it will give me Index Seek operation
for all these tested cases. but at certain point that index will also exhaust and become Index Scan.
one sure example would be if my filter value for A8 column is smallest date value exist in that column. in that case Optimizer will see that all 9M rows need to be participate in inner select and CUBE and lot of data will be get processed in memory. which is expected. on the other hand lets see the another example of queries. i have unique 32873 values in A8 column and those values are almost equally distributed among 9M rows. so per single A8 values there are 260 to 300 rows. now if I execute the query **for any single value** smallest, largest, or any thing in between the query execution time should not change.

notice the highlighted text in each image below that indicated what the value of A8 filter is chosen, 
important columns only in the select list instead using *, added A8 filter in the inner left join query, execution plan showing the TableScan operation on both table, query execution time in second,and total number of rows return by the query.

I hope that this will clear some doubts on performance of your query and will help you to set right expectation.

```
**Table Row Counts**
```

[image: Table Row Counts]

```
**TableScan_InnerLeftJoin**
```

[image: TableScan_InnerLeftJoin]

```
**TableScan_FullQuery_248Rows**
```

[image: TableScan_FullQuery_248Rows]

```
**TableScan_FullQuery_5K**
```

[image: TableScan_FullQuery_5K]

```
**TableScan_FullQuery_56K**
```

[image: TableScan_FullQuery_56K]

```
**TableScan_FullQuery_480k**
```

[image: TableScan_FullQuery_480k]

Comment: Hi Anup,I tried to use the concept of partial cube operation as suggested by you. Infact,i have implemented the same query that you have given me and yes output of the query is same.But,still execution time of the query is again more than 30-35s and it is keep on increasing when i am changing he value column i.e A8(Date_column).When i saw the explain plan cost of full table scan of table1 is around 80000.

Comment: Also,You suggested me to create the "non-clustered index on Table1 need on A3,A9and Table_reject need on B3,B2",but creating index on above mention column did not help me to bring down execution time and cost of query.As i mentioned the count of data in table1 is more than 8 million,may be the so high amount of data in table1 affecting the cost of query.The table structure is as follows: Table1: Column A1-A7(Varchar2,30 bytes),Column A8(Date)

Comment: can you give me the structure of both tables.  you already gave the data types for Table1 but also Null-Ability and same way structure for Table_reject as well, column name, dataType and NULL/Not NULL.

Comment: Check the Round3 edit. I modified the query with one more WHERE and create dummy data to show you the sample results. I do not have Oracle env. so I did replicate on SQL SERVER 2008R2 version. though this should be good benchmark to understand performance for query execution time and not query completion time. if my query is returning 5M rows in result set then   most of the time DB engine will spend is on just selecting the those rows and sending it to user/UI/file where ever the output mode is. and that is not query performance issue that something you can solve by Paging in DB or in APP.

Answer (score 0):

You're calculating a potentially very large cube result on seven columns, and then discarding all the results except those that are logically just a group_by on column A1.

I suggest that you rewrite the query to just group by A1.